# CiviEvent - Past event participants -> bulk register to new event

Tags: civievent, registration, advanced-search

Hi guys and thanks in advance.

I would like to find a way to do the following:

a. Advance Search
b. Find old event
c. Select participants
d. Action
**e. "Add relationship - register to event"**

In essence, I need to be able to use people that have registered (and may have come) to one of our previous events and register them to a new one.

Any way I can add that option under "Actions"? Or is there another way of going about doing this?

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I was able to search for these participants through Search>Advanced Search and use the Event Tab below instead, you should be able to see an Action of "Register Participants for Events" after selecting the participants.  This doesn't come out if you searched through Events>Find Participants though.

--CIVICRM 5.13.5 Wordpress 5.0--

Comment: Thx, that worked!